# Changing Domain on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I currently have some SQL Servers that sit on a sub-domain. We are eliminating that sub-domain and moving everything to the regular domain.

As far as SQL Server configuration goes, is there anything I need to change aside from potentially using different service accounts?

Note this is simply a domain change - the server name should be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did the same thing a while ago. The change went smoothly, we just had to change the various service accounts. We stopped all services before the move, then changed the accounts, then started everything without a hitch.

Comment: @Derek: yours should be the same. Changing the domains shouldn't include any problem out of the box, just check all the accounts and the connectivity between related servers.

Answer (score 2):

The domain name is part of the server name!  Open up SQL Server, SSMS, expand security for the server and look at the users.  Notice the Windows users are OldDomain\UserName?  It never changed.

Also do a SELECT @@SERVERNAME.  Notice it'll reference the old domain name.

Internally, SQL Server doesn't know the server changed domains and thus has a different 'fully qualified host name'.

Please do the following:
-Rename it with the correct name if it showed up as the old domain following [these instructions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)

-Make sure you have admin rights to the machine, and add the new domain users mirroring permissions off the old one.

Those would be the main steps needed to ensure a smooth domain rename.  Clustering is even more sensitive to it.

Comment: +1 for RTFM link but you are not correct. My SQL Servers 2012 `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` (as well as sys.servers) return: 1)old machine name (the one before renaming); 2)name without domain name. And all work for years. Actually "my" SQL servers recognize new server name for all purposes and fail to recognize the old one though the SQL Server metada has not been updated and return the old namу (and for quite a time)